# Передать код страны через SOCKS4

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, chrome-extension, vpn, socks5

```
Я пишу расширение для VPN, в нём необходимо передать код страны через SOCKS4 на локальный прокси. Как можно это грамотно сделать ?

Вот основной файл, если что, чтобы было понятнее:

// prettier-ignore
$(document).ready(function() {
loadData();
$("#search").click(search);
$("#clear").click(clear);

function loadData() {
chrome.storage.sync.get(["ip", "port", "countryId", "proxies"], function(result) {
if (result.ip && result.port) {
$("#cur_proxy").empty().append("Proxy set - " + result.ip + ":" + result.port + "");
} else {
$("#cur_proxy").empty().append("Proxy not used");
}

$("#country_id").val(result.countryId || null);

showProxies(result.proxies || null);
});
}

function search() {
const countryId = $("#country_id").val();
if (countryId === "select") {
alert("Select a country");
return;
}

const proxies = [];
let ip = "127.0.0.1";
let port = "1080";
proxies.push(ip + ":" + port);

showProxies(proxies);

chrome.storage.sync.set({countryId: countryId, proxies: proxies}, null);
}

function showProxies(proxies) {
$(proxies).each(function(i, proxy) {
$("#new_proxy").append('' + proxy + "");
});
$(".proxylist").on("click", function() {
const ip = "127.0.0.1";
const port = "1080";
setProxy(ip, port);
});
}

function setProxy(ip, port) {
const config = {
mode: "fixed_servers",
rules: {
singleProxy: {
host: ip`введите сюда код`,
port: port
}
}
};
chrome.proxy.settings.set({ value: config, scope: "regular" }, null);
chrome.storage.sync.set({ip: ip, port: port}, loadData);
}

function clear() {
const config = {
mode: "direct"
};
chrome.proxy.settings.set({ value: config, scope: "regular" }, null);
chrome.storage.sync.clear(loadData);
}
});
```

Comment: Протокол socks не поддерживает передачи каких либо данных кроме адресов для подключения. так что только делать свое расширение, которое должен будет понимать и ваш сервер и ваш клиент. при этом сторонние клиенты/сервера работать с ним не смогут

Comment: А Вы не могли показать тогда хоть примерный вариант реализации такого расширения?... Я просто не могу понять, как там всё произвести(((

Comment: Но я вижу вы в данном коде только что то делаете с настройками socks в хроме. хром не будет поддерживать ваши расширения. Я имел ввиду что если бы делали собственный сервер и собственный socks клиент (вместо хрома, а не дополняя его) то могли бы предусмотреть передачу при соединении например еще пары байт со страной

Comment: Как вариант вы можете свой socks сервер разместить на множестве портов и собственно номер порта на который идет соединение будет кодировать страну

Comment: Дело в том, что у нас разрабатываются отдельно сервер и прокси-сервер(клиентское приложение). Таким образом мне и нужно передать страну на последнюю штуку. Просто я уже не знаю, как сделать правильно, хотел передать в принципе страну в поле "пароль" и отдельно пользователя или просто, как часть заголовка ... Вы не могли бы продемонстрировать конкретную реализацию, если нетрудно ?

Comment: В итоге суть заключается в том, что в расширении из списка стран выбирается одна и передаётся на прокси.